# D&D 3.5e Equivalent of Pathfinder Suli Race

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, races

Is there a race in D&D 3.5e that is mechanically equivalent to the Suli from Pathfinder?

Comment: Equivalent in what way? Lore, mechanics, name, looks, something else?

Comment: Their Mechanics

Comment: Nothing can match *exactly*, but what about the suli makes it perfect your *3.5* needs? I mean, if you need a specific mechanical feature, that can probably be found in *3.5*, too.

Comment: I want the elemental resistance and elemental assault class features

Comment: Please edit those details into your question and we can probably get this question reopened to be answered.